# Check if variable contains a comma, without displaying the variable value

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do create a batch script to if else statement depending upon if a variable in question contains a "," comma without displaying the variable values.

I have a variable %PATHTMP% which could potentially be one of two values =

```
"       RS_Path = c:\data\RV\R\"
"       RS_Path = c:\data\RV\RS\,C:\data\RV2\RS2"
```

I want to identify if there is a , comma as this will allow me to determine if there are two paths in the variable.

This following work to achieve this, however if a "," is not present it displays the value of the %PATHTMP% in the command line window. I wish NOT to display the value.

```
@echo off
echo.%PATHTMP%|findstr /C:"," >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (
   echo Comma , found
) else (
    echo Comma , not found
)
```

The issue is the following line is display the value if no comma is present.

```
echo.%PATHTMP%|findstr /C:"," >nul 2>&1
```

Can anyone please advise on how to suppress the variable value in this line when a comma is not present. I've tried using >nul 2>nul without success. Alternatively how to re-write to achieve the same result with a if else as described without display the variable values in the command line. Not its important to display the command line as I am showing user reference information in the command line pre and post this command, so minimising or hiding thee command line windows is not a option.

Thank you

Comment: You are suppressing stdout and stderr correctly.

Comment: As already mentioned, you are doing it correctly, so I guess you did not provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

One other ways to check this is to try and remove a comma from the string to see if the variable is still equal to itself.

```
IF NOT "%PATHTMP:,=%"=="%PATHTMP%" echo comma found
```